# Under what engine conditions is glide performance typically determined in performance charts?

Tags: aircraft-performance, glide-ratio, engineering

The performance section of an information manual I am using states that the glide range indicated is "power off".

Does this terminology definitely imply that the engine is not firing? or could this also refer to an idle engine that is running, but producing nearly zero thrust, or even creating drag?

I assume, it means zero ignition, but cannot tell for sure from the document.

Comment: Power off means what it means.  No ignition or no fuel, and a windmilling prop which causes drag.

Comment: What sort of airplane is it?

Comment: This is regarding single-engine airplanes with reciprocating engines.

Comment: In Australia, it's with engine inoperative, see [page 47, Glide Performance](https://www.casa.gov.au/file/122726/download?token=NFLC3fMe).